# How do I prevent Pages from hyphenating a specific word?

Tags: pages, iwork, spellcheck

I have read [Wrap words in Pages](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/288324/wrap-words-in-pages) but my question is different. How do I prevent a specific word from being hyphenated (because Pages is wrong - "IS-P:er" (!!))?

I have a vague memory that there used to be a list of words, in the settings for Pages, that shouldn't be hyphenated but that might be in the "old" version of Pages (09? - when the icon was dark/black).

Comment: Does she web version of pages make hyphenation errors?

Comment: @bmike Yes it does.

Answer (score 1):

Source: [Pages User Guide](https://support.apple.com/en-ca/guide/pages/welcome/mac)
Source: [Q: How do I turn off auto-hyphenation on Pages 2.5 for iPad? Thanks!](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6760777)

> To turn hyphenation on or off for a word, click the word while holding down the Control key, and then choose Never Hyphenate or Allow Hyphenation from the shortcut menu.Turning hyphenation on or off for a word will affect every instance of that word in your document.

I can't find that quote in the guide but I'd try there.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Have you tried it?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't use Pages. You could call Apple Support and request support from the creative team they would be able to help. Or you could transition to another software but with pages I don't have much direct experience.

Answer (score 1):

The current version of Pages (v12.x) and all those launched since at least 2019, i.e. Pages v8.x and above, do not allow automatic hyphenation to be turned on or off on a word basis. It looks like this was possible with Pages v4.x launched in 2009, aka "Pages '09" (see "Automatic Hyphenation" on page 116 of [its manual](https://www.knoxschools.org/cms/lib7/TN01917079/Centricity/Domain/1238/Pages09_UserGuide.pdf)) but not sure if it were possible as well with any of the Pages versions launched after v4.x but before v8.x.

Comment: Now I remember! By mistake I had added a word to the never hyphenate-list. To remove that word I had to find some plist or similar somewhere deep in the Page 09-prefs and manually delete it.